# UIBarButtonItem (Weather)

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

[image]

In the bottom right hand corner of the weather application for iOS, there is a table/list like icon. I was wondering if this was a bar button item, or if this is a custom icon.

Comment: I would say a regular button.

Comment: @RashwanL However, when I try to add a UIBarButtonItem with one of Apple's system icons, there is not an option for this type of icon.

Comment: you mean the hamburger icon which says nothing about the hidden functionality behind it?

Comment: @luk2302 Yes, I mean that hamburger icon.

Comment: Nope, that is no buiit-in, you have to get hold of that yourself.

Comment: @RehaanAdvani, what I meant with regular button was custom button not a tabBar icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a custom button with a custom icon. To find all the template icons from Apple go to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html) site. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW34) is a list of all Tab Bar icons provided by Apple.